# Using ExecuteBatch from Python on Google Calendars API

Tags: python, batch-file, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to figure out how to add a series of events to a non-default calendar (and remove some) as a batch, but there's no hint of how to do it in Google's frankly awful documentation.

Has anyone cracked this nut or does anyone know where there is actually useful documentation on using the Google Calendar API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. The key is using the right batch URL in ExecuteBatch:

```
uri = self.calendar.GetAlternateLink().href
batch_uri = uri + u'/batch'
calendar_service.ExecuteBatch(request_feed, batch_uri)
```